# Is Scry on Familiar an obvious waste of time?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, familiars, saving-throw

I recently noticed that on top of getting a great level of spell resistance and inheriting their master's excellent base Will save bonus, [a Wizard's familiar](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/sorcererWizard#familiars) grants the *Scry on Familiar* (Sp) ability to its master, with the benefit:

> If the master is 13th level or higher, he may scry on his familiar (as if casting the [*scrying*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/scrying.htm) spell) once per day.

Is my mathematical intuition mistaken, or, even at level 13, will the familiar almost always block this, making it useless?

It's a "Spell Resistance: Yes" spell and it is negated by Will saves, both of which I suspect a Wizard's familiar to be great at.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mistaken. Scrying on your familiar is an upgrade to the earlier vague sense of how your familiar feels about, like, the world , man. But your familiar has to allow it, otherwise your intuition is right.

This is probably the piece you're missing: you can voluntarily skip SR and saving throws on spells. Per the [SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#savingThrow):

> **Voluntarily Giving up a Saving Throw**
>
> A creature can voluntarily forego a saving throw and willingly accept a spell’s result. Even a character with a special resistance to magic can suppress this quality.

Comment: Suppressing SR [costs a standard action](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellResistance). And you have to do it in advance of the spell, not in response. So this only works if you have coordinated with your familiar about when exactly you plan to scry.

Comment: @Topquark Not an issue, Speak with Master when I communicate this 'general emotional content' (I.E curiosity) via our empathic link, that will be your cue to lower your spell resistance.

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to get a bit subjective here, but I hope it's [Good Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). If you still think it's too subjective, take these as arguments that, Rules As Written, specific trumps general, and *scry on familiar* is stated as something you can **do**, not attempt.

Consider the following:

- *Share spells* allows spells to affect the familiar that otherwise could not.
- The familiar's *spell resistance* feature specifies (emphasis added): "To affect the familiar with a spell, **another spellcaster** must get a result on a caster level check (1d20 + caster level) that equals or exceeds the familiar’s spell resistance."
- *Scry on familiar* says the master can scry on the familiar. Not "attempt to", no mention of the usual attendant bonuses/penalties to saves against scrying, how familiar your familiar is, whether you kept some of its fur...
- Lowering spell resistance (as suggested in [fectin's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/175112/12144)) lowers it against *all* spells (and spell-like abilities), making your familiar notably vulnerable if you're using *scry on familiar* to let them scout for you.

All told, I think that this is pretty strong evidence for claiming that Rules As Intended, *scry on familiar* is an automatic success.

Comment: This was clearer prior to the *3.5* revision. The *Player's Handbook* (2000) on **Familiar Ability Descriptions** on *Spell Resistance* says, "If another spellcaster tries to affect someone else's familiar with a spell, that spellcaster must" check that familiar's spell resistance (51).

Comment: Incidentally, I think this is the right answer. Mine assumed that the asker had rejected this interpretation, but this is how I would rule it.